# Unable to use python-weka-wrapper in IPython/Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, installation, ipython, weka, jupyter-notebook

I've installed `javabridge` and `python-weka-wrapper` as shown in the [main site](http://pythonhosted.org/python-weka-wrapper/install.html) in my Mac. The following command seems to work on the command line interpreter.

```
import weka.core.jvm as jvm
jvm.start()
```

But it throws an error when tried at Jupyter Notebook like this

```
ERROR:weka.core.jvm:package_dir not found: /Users/Ebe/wekafiles/packages
```

What should I do to link the weka packages installed by `pip` to be accessible for Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/Users/Ebe/wekafiles/packages` directory is used by Weka's package manager, not `pip` for installing packages. This is just an error message, though erroneously output, as you didn't want packages to be loaded with your call and this directory doesn't seem to exist as of yet - [now fixed](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper/issues/45).